# How to refresh diagram when code changes and vice versa?

Tags: enterprise-architect

When I change a diagram, I want source code to update and when I change source code I want the diagram to update. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA does not automatically synchronize changes in either direction.

To update diagrams when source code changes:

> Click the "Save Source and Re-Synchronize Class" button on the source
> code editor toolbar, or
>
> Open Tools | Options | Source Code Engineering | Code Editors and enable the "Automatically Reverse Engineer

To update source code when diagram changes:

> Right-click the Package in the Project Browser which contains your classes and select Code Engineering | Live Code Generation.

For deleting an attribute and method in source code to work:

```
See: Tools | Options | Source Code Engineering | Attribute/Operations.
```

> Check On reverse synch, delete model associations not in code and
> delete model associations not in code as well as delete model methods
> not in code and prompt to delete code features not in model.